# не выходит установить Drag n Drop фичу в Angular на 2 компонента

Tags: html, css, angular

Всем привет,
Пишу проект, пытаюсь устанивить фичу уже 3 дня, ничего толкогого не нашел, чтобы помогло. компонент WorkSpace в него добавил Favourites компонент с картинами, внутри компонента Favourites могу перемещать картины без проблем. но если перетаскиваю их на WorkSpace то они замерзают и не могу их перемещать. Буду рад любой помощи или совету, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Очень размытое описание, не знаю поможет ли, но попробуй глянуть про [cdkDropList](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) (если ты используешь Cdk)

Так же если допустимо использование других библиотек, могу посоветовать UI библиотеку от [PrimeNG](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dragdrop) там очень легко имлементируемый DnD